# How do I get started with SyncAdapter and authentication?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, authentication

I have an Android app that store data in a SQLite database, but now I want to put together a two-way sync to a server (LAMP or maybe AppEngine).  The data will be account specific.  From what I can tell SyncAdapters are the way to go but there are a lot of pieces.  What advice/resources are there for getting started?

Answer (score 0):

This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE) gives a great overview of REST API strategies for android (including SyncAdapter)

This is a Udacity [course](https://www.udacity.com/course/viewer#!/c-ud853/l-1614738811/e-1664298704/m-1664298705) for begginers in sync adapter

other than this checkout official developer.android.com [guide](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html)

Hope this helps